# Is it possible to add space between legends in ios charts?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

So I want to add space between the legend of a multiple line chart. There is only the option to adjust center | left | right

What it looks like now - The labels are aligned according to the "label size":
[image]

What I want to look like - It should be 3 colums of 2 labels each Or maybe, add some space or set a minimum size for each legend:
[image]

This is the part of the code that enables the legend.

```
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = true
    lineChartView.legend.horizontalAlignment = .center
```

I've tried chartView.legend.stackSpace | chartView.legend.xEntrySpace | chartView.legend.yEntrySpace but nothing seems to change.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: please share some code that you use for that

Comment: just updated @Lu_

Comment: @Natan Martins have u found the solution for the above?

Comment: @ShilpashreeMC nope :/ My solution was to only draw the chart inside the view, and I added labels and views outside the chart view to do how I wanted. Each legend is a view (square) and a label.

Answer (score 4):

There is a property of Chart "extraBottomOffset" and its datatype is CGFloat, try to give some value and see the change

Answer (score 1):

PLease use `legend.yEntrySpace = "value"` for `legend.orientation = .vertical`.